# Which insulation for gap between plasterboard and subfloor?

Tags: insulation, carpentry

I have a room built under the roof on top of the garage, so eaves are directly behind the side walls. I removed the skirting boards to install the a new flooring and realized that there is a sizeable gap (up to 4 cm / 1.5") between some of the wall plasterboards and subfloor.

[image]

I'd love to put some insulation in there as these gaps would definitely allow the transit of cold air from eaves into the room. I would prefer the insulation to be removable if needed, so expanding foam is probably out of the question. What else could I use?

Comment: I would spray foam at the crack as it will seal the airspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard density foam board is probably your best option.  You can get 1.5" panels and cut them to size and get an R-7.5.
[image]

You could take batt insulation and compress it but batt insulation works best when not compressed and compressing it down to 1.5" would yield a [lower R value than the rigid foam](https://www.energyvanguard.com/blog/compressed-fiberglass-insulation-really-so-bad):

[image]